# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project binance-futures-connector-java

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, binance-api-client

the other day I tried to start using API from Binance. I stumbled across this library I found on Binance Git Hub (https://github.com/binance/binance-futures-connector-java). I never worked with Maven, so I was and still am quite a bit lost.
I followed the installation so firstly I downloaded ZIP. Unzipped it, went to the folder where was pom.xml file and from that path run command in cmd mvn install. I got this error:

```
Tests in error:
  testNewOrder(unit.cm_futures.account.TestCMNewOrder)
  testNewOrder(unit.um_futures.account.TestUMNewOrder)

Tests run: 302, Failures: 3, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.241 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-12T12:55:38+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project binance-futures-connector-java: There are test failures.
```

My pom.xml file is copy-paste what I downloaded

I see that error comes from tests in testNewOrder(unit.cm_futures.account.TestCMNewOrder) and testNewOrder(unit.um_futures.account.TestUMNewOrder), but I have no idea what to do.
I set the API and KEY in PrivateConfig.

I tried the following:

-Adding this piece of code to pom.xml

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.12.4</version>
</plugin>
```

-using command mvn clean install -U
Still getting the same error.

If I somehow fix this error later when I create a new project in IntelliJ IDEA. I choose Maven and in pom.xml just add(from installation instructions)

```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.github.binance</groupId>
>     <artifactId>binance-futures-connector-java</artifactId>
>     <version>LATEST_VERSION(1.0.0)</version>
> </dependency>
```

correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First the link in your question points to SO. Second `There are test failures.` this means you have test failures which you should fix first.. furthermore why do you use such extreme old version of surefire plugin? 
That: `<version>LATEST_VERSION(1.0.0)</version>` is simply wrong... and does not make sense... please show the test code which fails...

Comment: The link was correct it just redirected to SO.  I didn't code this library, it was downloaded from the link above, so about the old version of surefire, I don't know. The code about failed tests is in the files. LATEST_VERSION(1.0.0) was just an example, if I downloaded the 1.0.0 version then I would put <version>1.0.0</version>, if 2.0.0 then  <version>2.0.0</version